# Spring Cloud Gateway app hangs when synchronous call is made using webclient after 1 minute

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, project-reactor, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-webclient

**Spring cloud Gateway version: 4.1.0**

We are developing an API gateway application using Spring Cloud Gateway framework.
The application has couple of pre-filters and post-filters implemented as Global ordered filter.
We are developing a pre-filter as global filter that will validate the user session token to authenticate the incoming request before routing to the destination endpoint.
The user session token is validated using REST API exposed by another microservice.
The pre-filter is developed as follows:

```
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
   final String sessionToken = exchange.getRequest().getHeader().getFirst("sessionToken");
   final boolean isValid = restApiConnector.validateSessionToken(exchange, sessionToken) // REST API to validate token invoked using WebClient
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
     .publishOn(Scheduleers.boundedElastic())
     .toFuture().get();  // blocking call
   exchanges.getAttributes().put("sessionStatus", isValid);
   return chain.filter(exchange); 
}
```

restApiConnector is the connector class that uses Spring WebClient to call REST APIs. validateSessionToken is method that validates supplied token by calling validate session REST API using Spring WebClient.

The call to REST API is intentionally made blocking (synchronous) here since all the subsequent pre-filter are dependent on the outcome of this session validation pre-filter. Also the request will be routed to downstream endpoint only when session token is found to be valid by this pre-filter. Thus, pre-filter must execute before any subsequent pre-filter and downstream endpoint and any post filters.
*subscribeOn* and *publishOn* are used based on recommendation that long-lived I/O or network calls must be executed in different thread to avoid blocking the main Netty thread.

Above code works fine when request is sent to API gateway and the routing happens post session validation. In case the multiple requests are sent within one minute of last request, then the app works fine.
However, **if the request is sent after one minutes of last request (idle time), then the request processing gets hang** at the REST API invocation and no request is sent to session validation server. API Gateway app at this moment is able to accept subsequent incoming request however all subsequent requests shows same hang behavior.

Please guide on best practice on making synchronous call to network REST API calls in such scenarios.

We have already read multiple articles on the internet and mostly its mentioned to use **block()** call on the publisher, however it always results in exception for each request so toFuture().get() is used.
subscribe() cannot be used here since it will make the REST API invocation asynchronous and there can be chances that REST API might get invoked after the execution of pre-filter and post-filters which is not the expected flow for request processing.

Comment: You should never make a blocking call in the reactive gateway.

Comment: Never block in the `filter`. And based on your explanation and example, you don't need to block here at all, it would perfectly work without it.

Comment: Thanks @IgorArtamonov for reply. I already tried with async call using subscribe(consumer) however using that we observed that the validateSessionToken executes after routing to endpoint and post filters. How to make routing endpoint and post filters wait without using blocking call?

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb for your suggestion. How to execute rest API call in pre filter before routing to endpoint and post filters in reactive gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `block` or `subscribe` as this method (`filter`) already is a part of a reactive flow and returns a `Mono`.

Should be something like:

```
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
   final String sessionToken = exchange.getRequest().getHeader().getFirst("sessionToken");

   restApiConnector.validateSessionToken(exchange, sessionToken)
       .doOnNext { isValid -> 
           exchanges.getAttributes().put("sessionStatus", isValid)
       } 
       .then(chain.filter(exchange))
}
```

Proceed with the chain only if valid:

```
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
   final String sessionToken = exchange.getRequest().getHeader().getFirst("sessionToken");

   restApiConnector.validateSessionToken(exchange, sessionToken)
       .flatMap { isValid ->     
           if (isValid) {
               chain.filter(exchange)
           } else {
               ServerResponse.status(UNAUTHORIZED).build()
           }
       } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Igor Artamonov for the above code snippet. The pre-filter is able to get response from session validation REST API after adding then(chain.filter(exchange)). However, I have changed doOnNext to flatMap so that I can return Mono(Void) in filter chain. Now I am bit stuck in conditional scenario like if response of API is true then chain.filter(exchange) must be returned to continue the chain, however for false response, response.setComplete() must be return with UNAUTHORIZED status. But on this return value, API is again getting stuck. How to achieve such conditional return?

Comment: Basically, if response.setComplete() is returned instead of chain.filter(exchange) then session validation REST API does not get invoked by webclient and request gets hanged.

Comment: Thanks @Igor Artamonov for updated code. I am getting below compilation error for ServerResponse.status(UNAUTHORIZED).build() due to Mono<Object> not convertible with Mono<Void> type.

"no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that ServerResponse conforms to Void inference variable R has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: Void lower bounds: ServerResponse, Void"
Adding .then() in end converts it to Mono<Void>. Will try with this fix.

Comment: In further troubleshoot got to know that webclient response for invalid session token was getting received by error operator. The error operator was returning Mono.empty(). After adding switchIfEmpty with Mono.defer() in the assembly chain, its working fine with response.setComplete() as well :)